# How to convert $\text{m}^2$ to $\text{km}^3$?

Tags: calculus

A unit of area, often used in measuring land areas, is the "hectare", defined as $10^4\text{ m}^2$. An open-pit coal mine consumes $78$ hectares of land, down to a depth of $27\text{ m}$, each year. What volume of earth, in cubic kilometers, is removed in this time?

I think the solution is to multiply $78\cdot 10$ and $27\cdot\text{ m}^2$, so $780^4\cdot 27\text{ m}^2$. What next? Google doesn't show a method for converting $\text{m}^2$ to $\text{km}^3$.

Comment: You can not convert apples to pears. $\,\mathrm{m}^{2}$ is 'area'. $\,\mathrm{km}^{3}$ is 'volume'.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can not convert $\text{m}^2$ to $\text{km}^3$, because $\text{m}^2$ tells us something about the area and $\text{km}^3$ about a volume.

1. For one hectare, we find:
   $$1\space\text{hectare}=10000\space[\text{m}^2]=\frac{1}{100}\space[\text{km}^2]$$
2. For 78 hectare, we find:
   $$78\space\text{hectare}=780000\space[\text{m}^2]=\frac{78}{100}\space[\text{km}^2]=\frac{39}{50}\space[\text{km}^2]$$
3. To find the volume of the removed ground:
   $$\text{Volume}\space[\text{m}^3]=\text{L}\space[\text{m}]\cdot\text{W}\space[\text{m}]\cdot\text{D}\space[\text{m}]=780000\space[\text{m}^2]\cdot27\space[\text{m}]=$$
   $$21060000\space[\text{m}^3]=\frac{1053}{50000}\space[\text{km}^3]=0.02106\space[\text{km}^3]$$

Comment: How does 10 thousand m^2 equal 1/100 km^2? Where does the one-slash come from?

Comment: If $1$ km = $1000$ m, then $1$ km$^2$ = $1000^2$ m$^2$. In other words, $1$ m$^2$ = $\frac{1}{1,000,000}$ km$^2$.